# C programming socket sendto network is unreachable

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, udp

I'm trying to send a UDP packet to an address contained in argv[1] that can be either IPv4, IPv6, or a hostname. The UDP packet sends successfully when the address is IPv4, but when I use the hostname or the IPv6 address, sendto() throws errno 101 "sendto: Network is unreachable". Why is the network unreachable only when I do not use an IPv4? I'm running ubuntu 14.04 if that helps at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sockfd, ret;
    struct addrinfo ai_hints;
    struct addrinfo *ai_results;


    /* create an IPv6 UDP socket */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }

    /* find UDP IPv6 addresses from command line arg */
    memset(&ai_hints, 0, sizeof(ai_hints));
    ai_hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
    ai_hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    ai_hints.ai_flags = AI_V4MAPPED | AI_ADDRCONFIG; /* defaults */

    ret = getaddrinfo(argv[1], "12345", &ai_hints, &ai_results);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo(): %s\n", gai_strerror(ret));
        return 1;
    }

    ret = sendto(
        sockfd, "Hello World", 11, 0, 
        ai_results->ai_addr, ai_results->ai_addrlen
    );
    if (ret == -1) {
        printf("errno: %i\n",errno);
        perror("sendto");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What IPv6 address or hostname are you passing in?  Does IPv6 functionality work for that address/hostname from other programs (e.g. can you pass that same argument to ping6 and have it work there?)

Comment: I'm trying to pass in 2001:470:1f06:b9b::2, the address of a rendezvous server I have to communicate with for homework. I tried ping6 and I get "connect: Network is unreachable".

Comment: Does your localhost *have* IPv6? In any case as you can't `ping` the host this is not a programming question.

Comment: After trying with a valid IPv6 address, everything runs fine; thank you guys for your insight.